# Could use some advice with respect my solutions for showing the following set is not a vector space $S=\{(a, b) | a\geq b \} $

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Below are the two ways I would go about solving this. Is one way better than the other in terms of a solution for this problem, or are they both more or less equivalent? I ask because, in my book, I can't find a single example of a counterexample being used to disprove something in a vector space. They are all straightforward concerning the given axiom that fails.

**The problem**
Determine if the following set is a vector space. $S=\{(a, b) | a\geq b \} $

**My definitions**
Let $({a_0}, {b_0}), ({a_1}, {b_1}) \in V$,

Define Addition: $({a_0}, {b_0})+ ({a_1}, {b_1}) =({a_0}+{a_1}, {b_0}+{b_1})$
Define scalar multiplication: $k({a}, {b}) = ({k\cdot a}, {k\cdot b})$

From this definition it's clear that $S$ is closed under scalar addition since $({x_0 + x_1}) \geq ({y_0 + y_1})$

**Solution (1)**
If the constant, $k$, is negative by properties of inequalities, we must reverse the symbol to preserve the inequality relation. Given that k is negative, ${a\geq b} \rightarrow {k\cdot a\leq k\cdot b}$. so the set $S$ is not closed under multiplication, which means it's **not** a vector space.

**Solution (2)**
$Let\ k=-1,\ a=10,\land\  b=9$ then we have $(-1)(10, 9)=(-10, -9)$ and clearly $-10 < -9$ so the set $S$ is not closed under multiplication, which means it's **not** a vector space.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It is not closed under scalar multiplication: $(2,1)\in S$ but $-1\cdot (2,1)\not\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas are correct, but the way you have worded and defined things is a little off. At one point you talk about $S$ being closed under scalar multiplication under your definition, but later you show that it is not.

You want to make things as general as you can without assuming anything. I am going to assume that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and you are working in a real vector space.

Let $S = \{a,b~|~a \geq b\}$. Then $(2,1) \in S$ since $2 \geq 1$. But, $-1(2,1) = (-2,-1) \not\in S$ since $-2 < -1$. Thus, $S$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, and for **solution (1)**, what are your thoughts on leaving it just at that?

Comment: Also, those are the typical definitions for scalar multiplication and addition on a vector space; I need to define their behavior, then talk about the axioms I thought? I'm showing that the Axiom for addition is correct and fails for scalar multiplication.

Comment: (1) is close, but you need to actually show a counter example. This may be beyond what you have learnt, but you could have a vector space where the only scalar constant you are allowed to multiply by is $0$. In this case, there is no negative constant. So its always better to present a specific constant and a specific vector.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you.